# Wildcard subdomains in IIS7. Is it possible to make them like it is in Apache?

Tags: apache, iis-7, subdomain, wildcard

Is this possible to configure IIS7 to achieve the same functionality like Apache has regarding wildcard domains? I'm interested in routing user in ASP.NET web application based on subdomain user used in URL.

Something like is described here:

http://steinsoft.net/index.php?site=programming/articles/apachewildcarddomain

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The answer is No, IIS7 (still) does not support wildcard hostnames (see [this](http://dirk.net/2008/05/28/wildcard-host-header-binding-and-subdomains-with-iis7/)). If you want to serve multiple domain on one website, the only workaround for now, as notandy suggested, is using a dedicated IP and doing it with DNS, which does support wildcards.

#### 2013 Update

For completeness, IIS8 does not yet have this feature either.

#### 2016 Update

Finally, IIS 10 in Windows 2016 supports wildcard subdomains.

Comment: Im trying to think if there'd be a way to use the url rewriter to game this into working.. gotta think.

Comment: The problem is that those rewrite rules need a website to live in; a website needs bindings to come alive; and IIS doesn't support wildcard bindings, so we're back in square one. You can definitely have a website simulate serving multiple websites (for example with rewrite rules, as you mention), but you do need a dedicated IP to pull this off. In this case, DNS is essentially making up for IIS's flaw.

Comment: @DanielLiuzzi Actually, they don't. Think about ARR's routing rules that fire everything to a server farm. They're setup as rewrite rules on the server, and I'm beginning to think this might work. Just came across this requirement myself. Will feedback soon..

Comment: IIS in Windows 10 supports wildcard hostnames.

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra Do you have a link to support that? All I found was [this](http://forums.iis.net/post/2087398.aspx).

Comment: Actually, Yes. But you have to install extensions [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) e [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) for IIS.

Comment: IIS 10 now supports wildcards - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support

Comment: @RudiVisser I am surprised that you didn't write back, but I posted my own answer.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo URL Rewrite and ARR are not needed if you simply use IIS 10's native wildcard host name support. But yes, if for older IIS releases and you want to emulate the same behaviors, those two can help very much.

Comment: @LexLi Do you realize that my comment is older than IIS 10's release date right?

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo Windows 10/IIS 10 preview build was clearly available in April 2015, so "you have to ..." was not 100% even at that time.

Comment: @LexLi I wasn't making myself clear at the time, but I was addressing Daniel Liuzzi's comment "IIS doesn't support wildcard bindings" not Ranjith-Michael's. I won't even taking account a non-official release at the time because this question is about IIS7 ;)

Answer (score 16):

> Does IIS support wildcard host header? Can I capture and redirect
>   *.mydomain.com to one web site?

The answer is Yes/No. Yes, because you are
able to redirect *.mydomain.com to one
web site. No, because the magic is in
DNS and not IIS.

Here's how you do it:
At IIS MMC,
configure a web site with NO host
header, then assign an IP address to
the site. (if you have one IP address
in the box, then you can skip this).
With this, the web site will bound to
the specific IP and will listen to all
HTTP requests send to the IP, and you
are done :)

Next step is to make sure your name
resolution works for the wildcard
query and reply with the correct IP
address. If you using Microsoft DNS
service, it won't allow you to create
a '*' A record (assuming you already
created the domain zone in DNS MMC),
you need to do the following:

1. Navigate to `%windir%\system32\dns\`
2. Find the zone file. E.g.
   mydomain.com.dns, open it with Notepad
3. Add an entry. E.g.
    `*     A    IP.IP.IP.IP`
4. Save the zone data file
5. Reload the zone data
   in DNS MMC.

Take note that by doing this, all *
will response to the IP that you
configured earlier. E.g.
abc.mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com,
K2k.mydomain.com and etc.

To verify that it is working, try ping
utility `ping (insert anything here).mydomain.com`
and you should
get replies from IP.IP.IP.IP

Then try browsing, http:// (insert
anything here).mydomain.com/, you
should get the same web page that you
have configured.

[Source](http://web.archive.org/web/20120301164607/http://msmvps.com/blogs/bernard/archive/2005/03/22/39218.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot create a wildcard (*) A record in Microsoft's DNS, but you *can* create a wildcard `CNAME`. If all you are trying to do is direct all subdomains to a particular IP, this would work. For example, if you have an A record for `www.mydomain.com`, you could add a `CNAME` record for `*.mydomain.com` and point that at `www.mydomain.com`. The hostname in the request header will still be the subdomain, so your web app should be able to catch it and handle it if you want.

Comment: Clean and simple. Love it!

Answer (score 4):

You can use IIS if you use the Web Platform Installer (http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and install the "URL Rewrite" module.  If you add an "A" record like "*.example.com", this allows all sub-domains to be sent to your IIS server.  In the IIS server you simply add a URL rewrite rule to the default website to do whatever you wish, such as redirect to another URL. When a user enters, say, "xyz.example.com", you could redirect to "example.com", and point all unknown subdomains to the root domain.  The steps are:

1. Install Web Platform Installer: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

   Run it, search for "URL Rewrite", and install it.
2. Go to the default website, and open "URL Rewrite".
3. Click "Add Rule(s)" on far right side.
4. Name the rule and set the following:

   Requested URL: Matches the Pattern

   Using: Regular Expressions

   Pattern: (.*)

   Logical Grouping: Match All
5. Add a new condition (click the "Add.." button), and set:

   Condition Input: {CACHE_URL}

   Check if input string: Matches the Pattern

   Pattern (modify as needed): (http|https)://(.*?)\.rootdomain\.tld

   Click [OK].
6. Now scroll down to action and set:

   Action Type: Redirect

   Redirect URL (modify as needed): {C:1}://rootdomain.tld{R:0}

The "{C:#}" and "{R:#}" come from the test windows when you click the "Test pattern" buttons next to the regex pattern entries.  You can match part of a server value and reuse it later.

Also, you may want to checkout this tip on passing on the HTTP/HTTPS in the URL (the "{C:1}" in step 6 above): http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/url-rewrite-protocol-http-https-in-the-action

Comment: Redirection is generally speaking not ideal, as it changes the actual URL shown in browsers. Wildcard host name support does not change URLs at all, so a proper solution should use rewriting instead of redirection. I just post my answer as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2: Link is broken, upgrade to IIS 10, it supports wildcards now.

UPDATE:  This works for a while, after a while I became bombarded by multiple requests coming through.  I would not recommend this method.

Make sure that your DNS records are setup correctly (CNAME record of *->@) and it will work flawlessly.  Tested with multiple domains.

Link is broken now used to be
http://pzxc.com/apache-style-wildcard-hostname-rewrite-rules-in-iis

Comment: Upgrade to IIS 10, it supports wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

For users who cannot upgrade to IIS 10+, it is not very difficult to enable wildcard host name support via reverse proxy.

The HTTP example is as below, while other setup is just a few more steps.

1. Create a catch-all site which binds to *:80 and no host name.
2. Create first site which binds to *:8091 and no host name.
3. Create second site which binds to *:8092 and no host name.
4. Test out both sites and move on.
5. Install ARR and URL Rewrite module.
6. Create rewrite rules on the catch-all site to dispatch requests to the two sites,

   ```
   <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
           <rules>
               <rule name="site1" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url=".*" />
                   <conditions>
                       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*).site1.com$" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8091/{R:0}" />
               </rule>
               <rule name="site2" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url=".*" />
                   <conditions>
                       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*).site2.com$" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8092/{R:0}" />
               </rule>
           </rules>
       </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
   ```

> Note that at server level, ARR proxy mode must be turned on,

```
    <system.webServer>
        <proxy enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
```

> IIS 10 wildcard host name is simpler and also has better performance, because ARR has its overhead (but generally speaking negligible).