# Subdomains on IIS Express

Tags: iis, iis-express

I would like to set up my IIS Express development environment to mirror what will happen on live. On live, the website responds to subdomains, so valid urls will be:

- client1.mysite.com
- client2.mysite.com
- etc.

**First step: change localhost to a domain**

I've edited my hosts file and my project properties so that instead of using `localhost:1234`, I can use `www.mysite.dev`, as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709014/using-custom-domains-with-iis-express/32744234#32744234).

This works fine.

**Second step: allow subdomains**

Now I need to allow subdomains. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690621/214980), I set the bindings for the site in my `applicationhost.config` to:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
</bindings>
```

Now I'm getting 404 errors, when I browse to `www.mysite.dev`. What have I done wrong? Interestingly, it does serve the site on `mysite.dev`.

#### EDIT

Ok, I had it working for a little while, then I tried adding SSL, and that messed something up. I undid the SSL, but now the site works on `www.mysite.com` but not on any of the other subdomains, which are now 404ing. I tried deleting the IISExpress folder to get it back to where I had it (momentarily), but I can't get it working like it was.