# Point with N sub domains to one WebRole in Azure

Tags: azure, subdomain, azure-web-roles

Currently I'm trying to port a web application(ASP.NET MVC) to windows azure and have come across a point, I don't know how to solve.

The application is a multi tenant one. Every customer who registers, can enter a name for his instance and is able to surf the site later on over theenteredname.example.com. Further, the domain is used in an ActionFilter to switch between the databases.

How can I realize this in Windows Azure? I know that I must define a binding with defined hostHeader attribute, but as the subdomains a generated dynamically I would have to change the service definition every time a user registers and a new sub domain appears and redeploy it. But that is really not the way I want it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that IIS does not support subdomain wildcard mapping, see here [Wildcard subdomains in IIS7. Is it possible to make them like it is in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458757/wildcard-subdomains-in-iis7-is-it-possible-to-make-them-like-it-is-in-apache) for more information.

If you would still like to do this there is a solution here http://www.seoconsultants.com/windows/isapi/subdomains/ , but it requires:

- Ability to update DNS records
- IIS web server admin access
- ISAPI_Rewrite component (for Solution 2)

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Azure, if you simply don't assign any host headers to your web role (which is the default), the site will be configured to accept any host header.

You still need to configure wildcard DNS to point to your Azure instance, just as you would for a non-Azure solution.